# Is there a good online dictionary/encyclopedia for mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources

I'm an engineer/physicist by training, and typically, my publications are in journals where the readers do have an semi-advanced understanding of math, but not at a serious mathematician's level. So often, when I use some transform or a function that is not known to the community, I'd like to point them to a reference that's precise, yet simple to read and readily accessible. It seems unfair to point them towards a dense article/book that might be the best in the field, yet completely useless to someone reading my paper.

What I'm looking for, would be an online form of the [Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics](http://mitpress.mit.edu/catalog/item/default.asp?ttype=2&tid=7771) (EDM), which is a remarkable reference. This is my favourite option, but I'd like to know if there are online alternatives (by a trusted body, not a run of the mill math-o-pedias that float around), which makes access easier.

One that comes to mind is [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/) (WM), which although impressive, can be lacking at times (to put it this way, they have very good references on mathematical concepts that Mathematica is capable of doing). The [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) (DLMF) is not bad either, but doesn't come close to the EDM.

Lastly, Wikipedia (WP) is pretty decent, especially in conveying concepts to the lay reader. However the anyone-can-edit it feature makes it a little less reliable than the other three.

For now, my feeling is that EDM $\gt$ WM $\approx$ DLMF $\geq$ WP. Do you have suggestions?

If you think otherwise of my rating of the references, please do let me know why... perhaps I might have overlooked a few aspects in evaluating them and am open to reviewing them.

Comment: http://eom.springer.de/

Comment: For the things that are actually in DLMF, I would almost certainly rank it above WM. For mathematical concepts, the EOM that yoyo suggests is perhaps the best resource, though for specific transform/function, the EOM may not be all that different from just reading a book.

Comment: I don't believe anybody has attempted to make a compilation, much less an update, of the stuff on (integral and other) transforms in the Bateman papers... that would make for an interesting project, I reckon. And yes, I too would rate DLMF quite a bit above MathWorld. The Wolfram Functions site has stuff that the DLMF doesn't have, but not much.

Comment: @yoyo: Thanks for that link. It looks like a pretty well maintained  encyclopedia, and will probably replace most of my online options. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: If you read Japanese, the most recent (Japanese 4th) edition of [the Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics](http://www.iwanami.co.jp/moreinfo/0803090/top.html) has an accompanying CD-ROM that contains PDF files of the 4th and 3rd (equivalent to English 2nd) edition, which I find extremely convenient. (But of course they are not for free.)

Answer (score 2):

Other than wikipedia,  there's wolfram's site http://mathworld.wolfram.com/
and there's also a free collaborative encyclopedia at http://planetmath.org/

Answer (score 1):

www.wikipedia.org is the most comprehensive online mathematics resource I have found.  It is also extremely reliable, although at times a little opaque.

Comment: I agree and I like wikipedia. However, it certainly won't meet the standards in a peer reviewed journal specifically because it can be edited at will, and what I cite might not be what the reader views.

Comment: Agreed, it's no source for peer reviewed mathematics.  A good place to start finding peer reviewed info would be mathscinet or something, I guess.

Comment: @yoda: it is possible to cite any particular revision of some article. Have a look at the history tab of some article.

Answer (score 1):

http://encyclopedia-of-equation.webnode.jp/ is a nice website of mathematical identity equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Laplace transforms or other things then I wouldn't know of texts that have simple explanations to what they mean, in fact only by going through the mess of doing it can one understand even a bit of what's being said. So ultimately it depends on how much your readers do want to understand.

Since you're an engineer/physicist by training, you deal with a lot of differential equations so I suggest Morris and Tenenbaum's Ordinary Differential Equations, it's a great book and furthermore it's for students of science and engineering, I use it for my differential equations class.

In fact the chapter on Laplace Transforms is not hard at all, great for a quick reference.

But if you're invoking stuff from complex analysis then 100% I would suggest Needham's Visual Complex Analyis, it's not even that complicated and it's full of pictures that illustrate beautifully what's happening!

Good luck in finding what you need,
Ben

Comment: I don't think Laplace falls under "transform or a function that is not known to the community"

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm not looking for physical references (books)... I have good references for those. I was specifically looking for online resources.

Answer (score 0):

*[The Princeton companion to mathematics](http://site.ebrary.com/lib/arizona/docDetail.action?docID=10405145)* is also available online if you have an Ebrary subscription.